# Webpack Static Site Not Updating HTML

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a static site I am working on, using webpack as my build tool.

The site consists of a single HTML file, with a number of assets, it is also using Bootstrap and jQuery.

I can configured my webpack build to bundle everything up with minification and hashing, however, my images are not being included and webpack is not updating my html file, other than including the css and js bundles in the header and footer.

How can I get webpack to take my html file, update the references to images and copy this to my dist folder?

My Webpack looks like this....

**webpack.prod.js**

```
   const commonPaths = require('./common-paths');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    const config = {
      mode: 'production',
      output: {
        filename: 'assets/[name].[hash].min.js',
      },
      devtool: false,
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallback: 'style-loader',
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: { modules: false, importLoaders: 1, camelCase: false, sourceMap: false },
                },
                {
                  loader: 'postcss-loader',
                  options: { config: { ctx: { autoprefixer: { browsers: 'last 2 versions' } } } },
                },
              ],
            }),
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: 'assets/[name].[hash].min.css',
          allChunks: true,
        }),
      ],
    };
    module.exports = config;
```

webpack.common.js

```
const commonPaths = require('./common-paths');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModernizrWebpackPlugin = require('modernizr-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  entry: {
    app: [`${commonPaths.appEntry}/assets/index.js`],
    vendor: ['uglify-loader!bootstrap', 'uglify-loader!jquery'],
  },
  output: {
    path: commonPaths.outputPath,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /modernizr/,
        loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?window.Modernizr',
      },
      { test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery' },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: { cacheGroups: { vendor: { chunks: 'initial', test: 'vendor', name: 'vendor', enforce: true } } },
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModernizrWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'JS Webpack Starter',
      template: 'src/index.html',
      favicon: 'src/favicon.ico',
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
      hash: true,
      inject: 'body',
    }),
  ],
};
module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader is the answer.

Comment: I love people that answer their own questions after finding out the solution rather than just leaving it abandoned. Helps a lot of people that stumble onto the same issue later.